HTTP 404 Error using Undetected Chromedriver
Name: undetected-chromedriver
Version: 3.5.5
I know this was an issue in the previous version, I just updated UC though and still having the same issue.
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Untitled-2.ipynb Cell 3 line 2
      1 import undetected_chromedriver as uc
----> 2 driver = uc.Chrome()
      3 driver.get('https://chat.openai.com/chat')
HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found

Verified that download url was correct in patcher.py as suggested fix from past version.
Any help is appreciated

Unable to reproduce. Works fine with Python 3.12.3 and undetected-chromedriver 3.5.5
